# How to assign the label of one column to the new one based on per group maximum value of another column ? panda tranform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have the following sample data frame in pandas. How to get the maximum of '`label_weight`' value per '`Id`' and assign the corresponding '`label`' column to all raws of that '`Id`' in a new column '`assgined_label`'

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id', 'label_weight', 'label'])

df['Id'] = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']
df['label'] = ['H','H', 'H','M', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'L','H', 'H', 'L', 'L']
df['label_weight'] = ['30','30', '30','28', '29','31', '31', '30', '26', '26','28','28']
```

The required output should look like the following:

```
df['assgined_label'] = ['H','H', 'H','H', 'M','M', 'M','M', 'L','L', 'L','L']
```

[image]
I tried something similar but couldn't manage to produce the correct result.

```
df['assgined_label'] = df.groupby('Id')['label_weight']\
                         .transform(lambda x: x.max() x['label'])
```

I appreciate any help or tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for get values of index by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), because different index values with original is assigned numpy array:

```
#convert column to numeric
df['label_weight'] = df['label_weight'].astype(int)
#pandas 0.24+
df['assigned_label'] = (df.set_index('label')
                          .groupby('Id')['label_weight']
                          .transform('idxmax')
                          .to_numpy())

#pandas below 0.24
df['assigned_label'] = (df.set_index('label')
                          .groupby('Id')['label_weight']
                          .transform('idxmax')
                          .values)

print (df)
   Id  label_weight label assgined_label
0   A            30     H              H
1   A            30     H              H
2   A            30     H              H
3   A            28     M              H
4   B            29     H              M
5   B            31     M              M
6   B            31     M              M
7   B            30     L              M
8   C            26     H              L
9   C            26     H              L
10  C            28     L              L
11  C            28     L              L
```